# Setting up a local webserver with switchable PHP versions using a virtual machine

Tags: php, macos, ubuntu, web-development-server

I've used XAMPP for local web development for a number of years, but I'm becoming increasingly frustrated with its limitations and would like to switch to a different solution.

What I'm looking for is something that will easily allow me to switch between different versions of PHP. The plan I've got in mind at the moment is to set up a local version of Ubuntu via Parallels (I seem to remember that I'll only need the Desktop edition of Ubuntu and not the Server addition to do what I want to do) and then to use this to provide a web server to the Mac OS X host that will be available at `http://localhost/`.

I suppose the ideal solution would enable me to have multiple web servers running from the same Ubuntu virtual machine, so that `http://localhost-529/` was a web server running php 5.2.9, `http://localhost-531/` was a web server running PHP 5.3.1, etc.

Is this possible? And is the idea I've outline the way to proceed, or is there a better way to get this setup working?

Answer (score 2):

you should take a look at [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

eg it could be possible to do the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.localhost-529
   ServerAlias localhost-529
   LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
   ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.localhost-4
   ServerAlias localhost-4
   LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

the names localhsot-529, localhost-4 have to entered in the hosts file of your clients

Comment: So would this mean that if I had a PHP script called script.php in webroot, http://www.locahost-529/script.php would execute the script using PHP 5.2.9 and http://www.localhost-5/script.php would execute the script using PHP 4? And is it possible to do a similar thing but using different ports on the same URL rather than different URLs? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can call localhost-529/script.php to parse it in php5 or localhost-4 to parse it in php4. Yes it might be possibel too, take a look at the manual, virtualhost can use different ports or different uris. BTW the DocumentRoot must in your example be the same in each vhost configuration